# Best way to connect multiple 4k @ 60Hz monitors to a discrete GPU or laptop?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

- I've got a desktop PC with a discrete GPU that outputs DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI-D.
- I've got a laptop with a USB-C port.
- I've got two 4k monitors with HDMI and DisplayPort inputs.
- I want to extend my desktop across the monitors at 60Hz. Meaning, we've got to output two separate 4k @ 60Hz feeds.
- I'd like to use the same mechanism/hub to connect the monitors to the PC and laptop. That way I can just change the input from the laptop to the PC without needing to unplug anything on the monitor end.

While there are many USB-C to DisplayPort hubs, they all had poor reviews. Surprisingly, I ran across a USB-C to HDMI hub that had excellent reviews: https://www.amazon.ca/Adapter-Converter-Compatible-MacBook-Samsung/dp/B07QKVY23Q/

Unfortunately, per [USB-C Monitor on a Desktop with Discrete GPU](https://superuser.com/q/1467471/57662) it doesn't look like we'll be able to connect a discrete GPU output to a USB-C input.

So as far as I can tell, my best option is to use a different connection mechanism for the laptop and PC. I'd use the USB-C to HDMI hub to connect the monitors to the laptop. When connecting them to the desktop PC I will need to use separate HDMI, DisplayPort connectors.

Is anyone aware of an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying a Thunderbolt to 2xDisplayPort adapter: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B079JJ2MTR/. It's been a couple of months now and it works great.